# Ansible set_facts based on OS version not working

Tags: ansible

I want to set the patch based on the OS version. Came up with this playbook in Ansible version 2.8. But it's giving `The task includes an option with an undefined variable.` error message in the debug line.

```yaml
---
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: yes
  vars:
      patch_name_8: 'centos8-updates'
      patch_name_7: 'centos7-updates'
  tasks:
    - name: Set fact for CentOS 7
      set_fact:
        install_patch_name: "{{ patch_name_7 }}"
      when: ansible_distribution_major_version == 7

    - name: Set fact for CentOS 8
      set_fact:
        install_patch_name: "{{ patch_name_8 }}"
      when: ansible_distribution_major_version == 8

    - name: patch name display
      debug:
        msg: "install {{ install_patch_name }}"
```

How can I set the `install_patch_name` variable value based on the OS version?

This is the error message:

```
TASK [patch name display] ************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [host01]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'install_patch_name' is undefined\n\nThe error appears to be in 't.yaml': line 23, column 7, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n
- name: patch name display\n      ^ here\n"}
```

Comment: While this isn't what you asked, isn't the thing you want to `set_fact:` `install_patch_name: centos{{ ansible_distribution_major_version }}-updates`?

Comment: Also, with almost 12k reputation, surely you know better than to post a question like that without including logs or the output of `debug: var=ansible_distribution_major_version` that would enable someone to, you know, actually help you

Comment: @mdaniel, Apologize not including the error message. added it now.

Comment: The needed information (that I guessed in my below answer) would have been the complete playbook result where everyone could have seen each `set_fact` action was actually skipped.

Answer (score 6):

## TL;DR

Use

```yaml
when: ansible_distribution_major_version == "8"
```

or

```yaml
when: ansible_distribution_major_version | int == 8
```

## Explanation

Note: all following examples have been played against a `centos:8` docker image.

The fact your are looking after is returned as a string :

```
[root@f6408271fc8c ~]# ansible localhost -m setup -a filter=ansible_distribution_major_version
localhost | SUCCESS => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "ansible_distribution_major_version": "8"
    },
    "changed": false
}
```

Variables keep their types when using comparison and need to be correctly casted if need be, as demonstrated by the following playbook.

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  
  tasks:
    - name: default compare
      debug:
        msg: Comparison is true
      when: ansible_distribution_major_version == 8

    - name: compare as strings
      debug:
        msg: Comparison is true
      when: ansible_distribution_major_version == "8"

    - name: compare as ints
      debug:
        msg: Comparison is true
      when: ansible_distribution_major_version | int == 8
```

Which gives

```
[root@f6408271fc8c ~]# ansible-playbook play.yml 

PLAY [localhost] **************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [default compare] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
skipping: [localhost]

TASK [compare as strings] *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "Comparison is true"
}

TASK [compare as ints] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "Comparison is true"
}

PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=3    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=1    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Answer (score -1):

Probably because the permission, you need to be admin for gather system info.
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_privilege_escalation.html